# Restrict the values in an arraylist?

Tags: java

If my list can contain values of 1 or 2 in it and I get the list at runtime and it isn't possible for me to modify it then what's the best way to check and report an error if it does contain any other values ? Do I need to examine each and every element against values of 1 and 2 to make sure no other values are contained in the list.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: "*report an error if it doesn't contain any other values*" is the opposite of "*make sure no other values are contained in the list*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get the list from an external source, you need to check each element of the list for a value to be in the correct range. If you make the list yourself, you can inherit `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, and override the mutating members (`add`, `insert`, etc.) to check the values at insertion points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're handed an existing list and want to make sure it only contains certain values you have to search all the cells there is no better algorithm.
In other words the best algorithm for searching in a non-sorted list is O(N).